# HTML cannot retrieve Payment Button created in Coinbase Sandbox environment

Tags: sandbox, coinbase-api

Coinbase newbie here.
Testing Coinbase in Sandbox environment, cannot get the Payment button to show in an HTML page. Traced it to button.js trying to retrieve the Payment Button code from `www<dot>` instead of `sandbox<dot>`.

Here is the scenario:

1. Using the "Sandbox" environment.
2. Generated the button-code with an API call to https://api.sandbox.coinbase.com/v1/buttons
   All the API security/authentication stuff working fine.
3. Using the [button-code] generated in 2. Test checkout screen by typing https://sandbox.coinbase.com/checkouts/[button-code] directly in the browser.
   Result: Browser displays the checkout screen for my Merchant account. Cool.
4. Using the [button-code] generated in 2. Test button by typing https://sandbox.coinbase.com/buttons/[button-code] directly in the browser. Result: Browser displays a nice button. Cool again.
5. Place this code in an HTML page:

   ```
   <a class="coinbase-button" data-code="[button-code]"  href="https://sandbox.coinbase.com/checkouts/[button-code]">Donate Bitcoins </a>
    <script src="https://sandbox.coinbase.com/assets/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```

On the browser screen this is what happens: it displays the link "Donate Bitcoins" for a brief moment then it replaces the link with the text "Invalid data-code attribute (1)"

Monitoring the HTTP traffic I see the error comes from the behind-the-covers call to retrieve the button, it goes to: https://www.coinbase.com/buttons/[button-code] --- it should go to `sandbox<dot>` as in step 4 above, not `www<dot>`

The source sandbox.coinbase.com/assets/button.js has hard-coded www.coinbase.com. This is wrong, although I cannot believe I am the first one to have run into this problem, so I am allowing for the fact I may be doing something wrong.

Will Coinbase fix the button.js code in the Sandbox environment ?

Answer (score 2):

This answer from a duplicate of this question on coinbase forums ([source](https://community.coinbase.com/t/coinbase-sanbox-and-buttons/1605/6))

The trick is to set `data-env="Sandbox"` on the button div, and the script will correctly adjust the domain.

`<div class="coinbase-button" data-env="sandbox" data-code="xxxx">`